# DataGenerator error in Keras only after import from different file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am using a jupyter notebook to run python code with the following file structure:

> ### File structure
>
> ```
> Main_jupyter_file.ipynb
> dataloader.py
> ```
>
> ### Main_jupyter_file.ipynb
>
> ```
> from dataloader import DataGenerator
> training_generator = DataGenerator(...)
> model = ...
> model.compile(loss=...optimizer='adam')
> model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,\
> use_multiprocessing=True,workers=8, epochs=2)
> ```
>
> ### dataloader.py
>
> ```
> class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
>     def __init__(self, ...):
>
>     def __len__(self):
>     'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
>         return ...
>
>     def __getitem__(self, index):
>         return ...
> ```

After running `model.fit_generator` I receive a warning and an error:

#### Warning:

WARNING:tensorflow:Using a generator with `use_multiprocessing=True` and multiple workers may duplicate your data. Please consider using the`keras.utils.Sequence class.

#### Error:

`steps_per_epoch=None` is only valid for a generator based on the `keras.utils.Sequence` class. Please specify `steps_per_epoch` or use the `keras.utils.Sequence` class.

**I get the same results with tf.keras and native Keras.**

## Weird finding

When I copy the code of the DataGenerator class from dataloader.py into the jupyter notebook document, then I don't get any errors or warnings and everything works fine.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this, its a very localized problem, maybe you just have old code that uses Generator somewhere and you are importing that.